# jsf namespace not found

Tags: xml, jsf

Not sure if this problem is old or not but i can't locate the namespaces

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

for example this namespace

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

is available for me

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the JSF JAR file(s) are in the webapp's classpath. They namely contain the necessary `.taglib.xml` file(s).

How to do that depends on your development environment and the targeted server which you didn't tell anything about in your question.

If you're using for example Eclipse and Tomcat, then you'd need to manually download the JSF JAR file(s) from the vendor's site and drop them in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Eclipse will then do the necessary magic. Or, if you're using a server which already ships with JSF bundled, such as Glassfish, JBoss AS, etc, then you'd need to integrate it in *Servers* view of Eclipse and then set it as *Targeted Runtime* of your Eclipse project in the project's properties. Eclipse will then do the necessary magic.

Comment: jsf jars you mean jsf-api and jsf-impl? i use jboss7 and idea ic

Comment: JBoss already ships with JSF bundled, so you don't need to download/include it manually. I don't use IntelliJ IDEA, so I have no idea, but the principle is the same as in Eclipse: to the point you need to associate the web project with the JBoss server as target runtime, so that the IDE will auto-include all the server-provided libraries in the project's build path (aka the classpath).